# Cognos Issues displaying a calculated date in a Report expression

Tags: cognos

In Cognos 10.1 Report Studio, I am having an issue displaying a calculated date.  In an attempt to calculate the previous date based on a date prompt and display it in a report header, I have tried the following:

_add_days(_make_timestamp(
 string2int32 (substring(ParamValue('p_AsOfDate'),1,4))
,
string2int32 (substring(ParamValue('p_AsOfDate'),6,2))
,
string2int32 (substring(ParamValue('p_AsOfDate'),9,2))
),-1)

for 7/1/2016, it returns "00/30/2016"

Note that ParamValue('p_AsOfDate') returns 2016-07-01. I laboriously extracted and tested each piece

_make_timestamp(2016,06,30) returns "00/30/2016"

Is this a bug, or am I missing something obvious.

Comment: I could not replicate your results. I copied the expression above and for 2016-07-01 I got Jun 30, 2016 12:00:00 AM in the report header. I am using 10.2.2 rather than 10.1, so I don't know if this is a bug in 10.1 that was subsequently fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts.

Comment: I got around it.  As best as I can explain, the report expression was of data type date.  Changing the data type to text fixed the issue.  Thanks again for your help Johnsonium.